# Trouble separating data within buffer (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, buffer

I found this piece of code online that promises to separate data loaded into the buffer, I need that so I may display each .bmp image individually on the screen.

```
BOOL OpenBmpFile(char* filePath, char* fileName, int* offset, HWND hwnd)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;            
    char szFileName[256];    
    char szFilePath[256];
    BOOL FileOK;         

    memset(&ofn, 0, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)\0*.bmp\0\0");
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    strcpy(szFilePath, "*.bmp");
    ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFilePath;
    //
    // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
    // use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
    //
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFilePath);
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = (LPWSTR)szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = sizeof(szFileName);
    ofn.lpstrTitle = TEXT("Open BMP File");
    ofn.Flags = OFN_SHOWHELP | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_LONGNAMES | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_EXPLORER;


    // show the common dialog "Open BMP File"
    FileOK = GetOpenFileName(&ofn);

    // if cancel, exit
    if (!FileOK)
        return FALSE;

    // else store the selected filename
    strcpy(fileName, szFileName);
    //I use this because strcpy stops after the first NULL
    memcpy(filePath, szFilePath, sizeof(szFilePath));
    *offset = ofn.nFileOffset;

    if(szFilePath[ofn.nFileOffset-1] != '\0')
    {
    MessageBox(hwnd,L"Single Selection",L"Open Debug 1",MB_OK);
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox(hwnd,L"Multiple Selection",L"Open Debug 2",MB_OK);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

However, every time I call this function with the following line results in an error:

```
OpenBmpFile((char*)file, (char*)file2, pTest, hWnd);
```

Error: pTest is a nullptr;

I guess my question is, how may I use this function effectively to display my images?

Comment: Passing `pTest` with allowed value, in other words something like `int pTest; OpenBmpFile((char*)file, (char*)file2, &pTest, hWnd);`

Comment: Thank you, for some reason it's saying "Multiple Selection" even when I open just one .bmp image. :/ I've been having this issue for a whole day I'm really sick of it. If only WinAPI can simplify things... though it is an old language after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest mistake you are making is mixing ANSI and Unicode together.  You are using `char[]` buffers and type-casting them to `LPWSTR` pointers in order to assign them to the `OPENFILENAME` fields.  Since you are using the `TCHAR` version of the API, that means your project is being compiled for Unicode, not for ANSI.  Thus the API is expecting Unicode buffers, and will output Unicode strings.  Which also means you are telling the API that *twice* your buffers' allocated space is available to receive characters, since you are setting the `ofn.nMaxFile` and `ofn.nMaxFileTitle` fields to *byte* counts instead of *character* counts.  So you can cause buffer overflows.

You cannot merely typecast an 8-bit buffer to a 16-bit data type.  You have to use the correct data type for your buffer to begin with, and get rid of the type-casts.  In this case, that means using `WCHAR`/`wchar_t` (or at least `TCHAR`) buffers instead of `char` buffers.  But, since you are using `char` in your function parameters, you should use the ANSI version of the API instead of the `TCHAR`/Unicode version.

When selecting multiple files, especially files with long filenames, the resulting character data can easily grow beyond the size of your fixed-length buffer.  As the [`OPENFILENAME` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) states:

> lpstrFile
>   Type: LPTSTR
>
> The file name used to initialize the File Name edit control. The first character of this buffer must be NULL if initialization is not necessary. When the `GetOpenFileName` or `GetSaveFileName` function returns successfully, this buffer contains the drive designator, path, file name, and extension of the selected file.
>
> If the `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` flag is set and the user selects multiple files, the buffer contains the current directory followed by the file names of the selected files. For Explorer-style dialog boxes, the directory and file name strings are NULL separated, with an extra NULL character after the last file name. For old-style dialog boxes, the strings are space separated and the function uses short file names for file names with spaces. You can use the `FindFirstFile` function to convert between long and short file names. If the user selects only one file, the `lpstrFile` string does not have a separator between the path and file name.
>
> **If the buffer is too small, the function returns `FALSE` and the `CommDlgExtendedError` function returns `FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL`. In this case, the first two bytes of the `lpstrFile` buffer contain the required size, in bytes or characters**.
>
> nMaxFile
>   Type: DWORD
>
> **The size, in characters, of the buffer pointed to by `lpstrFile`**. The buffer must be large enough to store the path and file name string or strings, including the terminating NULL character. **The `GetOpenFileName` and `GetSaveFileName` functions return `FALSE` if the buffer is too small to contain the file information. The buffer should be at least 256 characters long**.

You are not taking that into account.  256 (better to use 260, aka `MAX_PATH`) is OK for selecting a single file, but may not be OK for selecting multiple files.  If `GetOpenFileName()` fails with `FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL`, you will have to reallocate your buffer and call `GetOpenFileName()` again.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
BOOL OpenBmpFiles(char **filePath, char** fileNames, HWND hwnd)
{
    *filePath = NULL;
    *fileNames = NULL;

    size_t iMaxFileSize = MAX_PATH;
    char *lpFileBuffer = (char*) malloc(iMaxFileSize);
    if (!lpFileBuffer)
        return FALSE;

    char szFileTitle[MAX_PATH];
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;

    OPENFILENAMEA ofn;            
    memset(&ofn, 0, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Bitmap Files (*.bmp)\0*.bmp\0\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFile = lpFileBuffer;
    ofn.nMaxFile = iMaxFileSize;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = szFileTitle;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = "Open BMP File";
    ofn.Flags = OFN_SHOWHELP | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_LONGNAMES | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_EXPLORER;

    do
    {
        //
        // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
        // use the contents of lpstrFile to initialize itself.
        //
        ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';

        // show the common dialog "Open BMP File"
        if (GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn))
            break;

        // if cancel, exit           
        if (CommDlgExtendedError() != FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL)
            goto cleanup;

        // reallocate the buffer and try again
        iMaxFileSize = * (WORD*) lpFileBuffer;
        char *lpNewFileBuffer = (char*) realloc(lpFileBuffer, iMaxFileSize);
        if (!lpNewFileBuffer)
            goto cleanup;

        lpFileBuffer = lpNewFileBuffer;

        ofn.lpstrFile = lpFileBuffer;
        ofn.nMaxFile = iMaxFileSize;
    }
    while (true);

    if (lpFileBuffer[ofn.nFileOffset-1] != '\0')
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Single Selection"), TEXT("Open Debug 1"), MB_OK);

        // copy the single filename and make sure it is double-null terminated

        size_t len = strlen(&lpFileBuffer[ofn.nFileOffset]) + 2;

        *fileNames = (char*) malloc(len);
        if (!*fileNames)
            goto cleanup;

        strncpy(*fileNames, &lpFileBuffer[ofn.nFileOffset], len);

        // copy the directory path and make sure it is null terminated

        lpFileBuffer[ofn.nFileOffset] = '\0';

        *filePath = strdup(lpFileBuffer);
        if (!*filePath)
        {
            free(*fileNames);
            *fileNames = NULL;
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Multiple Selection"), TEXT("Open Debug 2"), MB_OK);

        // copy the directory path, it is already null terminated

        *filePath = strdup(lpFileBuffer);
        if (!*filePath)
            goto cleanup;

        // copy the multiple filenames, they are already double-null terminated

        size_t len = (ofn.nMaxFile - ofn.nFileOffset);

        *fileNames = (char*) malloc(len);
        if (!*fileNames)
        {
            free(*filePath);
            *filePath = NULL;
            goto cleanup;
        }

        // have to use memcpy() since the filenames are null-separated
        memcpy(*fileNames, &lpFileBuffer[ofn.nFileOffset], len);
    }

    bResult = TRUE;

cleanup:
    free(lpFileBuffer);
    return bResult;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
char *path, *filenames;
if (OpenBmpFiles(&path, &filenames, hwnd))
{
    char *filename = filenames;
    do
    {
        // use path + filename as needed...
        /*
        char *fullpath = (char*) malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(filename)+1);
        PathCombineA(fullpath, path, filename);
        doSomethingWith(fullpath);
        free(fullpath);
        */

        filename += (strlen(filename) + 1);
    }
    while (*filename != '\0');

    free(path);
    free(filenames);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: alternatively, to simplify the use of the returned filenames, you could do something more like this:

```
BOOL OpenBmpFiles(char** fileNames, HWND hwnd)
{
    *fileNames = NULL;

    size_t iMaxFileSize = MAX_PATH;
    char *lpFileBuffer = (char*) malloc(iMaxFileSize);
    if (!lpFileBuffer)
        return FALSE;

    char szFileTitle[MAX_PATH];
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;

    OPENFILENAMEA ofn;            
    memset(&ofn, 0, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Bitmap Files (*.bmp)\0*.bmp\0\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFile = lpFileBuffer;
    ofn.nMaxFile = iMaxFileSize;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = szFileTitle;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = "Open BMP File";
    ofn.Flags = OFN_SHOWHELP | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_LONGNAMES | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_EXPLORER;

    do
    {
        //
        // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
        // use the contents of lpstrFile to initialize itself.
        //
        ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';

        // show the common dialog "Open BMP File"
        if (GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn))
            break;

        // if cancel, exit           
        if (CommDlgExtendedError() != FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL)
            goto cleanup;

        // reallocate the buffer and try again
        iMaxFileSize = * (WORD*) lpFileBuffer;
        char *lpNewFileBuffer = (char*) realloc(lpFileBuffer, iMaxFileSize);
        if (!lpNewFileBuffer)
            goto cleanup;

        lpFileBuffer = lpNewFileBuffer;

        ofn.lpstrFile = lpFileBuffer;
        ofn.nMaxFile = iMaxFileSize;
    }
    while (true);

    if (lpFileBuffer[ofn.nFileOffset-1] != '\0')
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Single Selection"), TEXT("Open Debug 1"), MB_OK);

        // copy the single filename and make sure it is double-null terminated

        size_t len = strlen(lpFileBuffer) + 2;

        *fileNames = (char*) malloc(len);
        if (!*fileNames)
            goto cleanup;

        strncpy(*fileNames, lpFileBuffer, len);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Multiple Selection"), TEXT("Open Debug 2"), MB_OK);

        // calculate the output buffer size

        char *path = lpFileBuffer;
        size_t pathLen = strlen(path);
        bool slashNeeded = ((path[pathLen-1] != '\\') && (path[pathLen-1] != '/'));
        size_t len = 1;

        char *filename = &lpFileBuffer[ofn.nFileOffset];
        while (*filename != '\0')
        {
            int filenameLen = strlen(filename);
            len += (pathLen + filenameLen + 1);
            if (slashNeeded) ++len;
            filename += (filenameLen + 1);
        }

        // copy the filenames and make sure they are double-null terminated

        *fileNames = (char*) malloc(len);
        if (!*fileNames)
            goto cleanup;

        char *out = *fileNames;

        filename = &lpFileBuffer[ofn.nFileOffset];
        while (*filename != '\0')
        {
            strncpy(out, path, pathLen);
            out += pathLen;
            if (slashNeeded) *out++ = '\\';

            int filenameLen = strlen(filename);
            strncpy(out, filename, filenameLen);
            out += filenameLen;
            *out++ = '\0';

            filename += (filenameLen + 1);
        }

        *out = '\0';
    }

    bResult = TRUE;

cleanup:
    free(lpFileBuffer);
    return bResult;
}
```

```
char *filenames;
if (OpenBmpFiles(&filenames, hwnd))
{
    char *filename = filenames;
    do
    {
        // use filename as needed...
        /*
        doSomethingWith(filename);
        */

        filename += (strlen(filename) + 1);
    }
    while (*filename != '\0');

    free(filenames);
}
```

Comment: Hey Remy, thank you so much for the information. I knew I couldn't get away with just typecasting like that. Thing is, I am quite new to WinAPI and I am not a big fan of its syntax, though I'm forcing myself to create an app with it. Anyway, would you kindly be able to have a look at my full code so far (here: http://textuploader.com/dtchw) and tell me how I should utilize it? Because currently my loading bitmap function isn't accepting the char* filename and I don't want to do any typecasting.

Comment: @FearlessHobbit this code I have given you keeps the directory and filenames separate, even for single selection.  Your loop will need to combine them back together, such as with [`PathCombine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx), before calling `LoadAndBlitBitmap()`. I chose not to make `OpenBmpFiles()` prefix each reported `filename` with the same `path` to save memory.  It would be trivial to change that behavior, though.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, I will try to combine them then, hopefully it's not too difficult to combine them, I'll let you know how things go. Thank you so much for your help. By the way, just to let you know, the idea behind my program is to make an application that loads bitmaps concurrently using multithreading.

Comment: Okay cool, I think that's better. By if `(insertSlash) *out++ = '\\';` Did you mean to put `slashNeeded` as the expression instead?

Comment: Oh and also do you think you can give me an example of how to make this load images with PathCombine()? That'll be very helpful.

Comment: @FearlessHobbit yes, it should have been `slashNeeded`. And you don't need `PathCombine()` with the newer code, only the earlier code

Comment: Wonderful, it works great now. I'm so glad I surpassed this problem. Now onto the next challenge, multi-threading! :p Given the current state of my code, do you think it's hard to implement a simple multi-threading mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

`nFileOffset` is the offset from the beginning of `lpstrFile` to the file name:

> if `lpstrFile` points to the following string, `"c:\dir1\dir2\file.ext"`, this member contains the value 13 to indicate the offset of the `"file.ext"` string. If the user selects more than one file, `nFileOffset` is the offset to the first file name.

According to this, `szFilePath[ofn.nFileOffset-1]` will point to the `\`. `lpStrFile` is defined as:

> ...If the `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` flag is set and the user selects multiple files, the buffer contains the current directory followed by the file names of the selected files. For Explorer-style dialog boxes, the directory and file name strings are NULL separated, with an extra NULL character after the last file name.

So, to determine if the user has selected more than one file, go to the end of `lpstrFile` (i.e., to the first null), then check if there is another null following it, if not, then the user selected multiple files.

To construct the full path and filename of each file, reuse the part up to `nFileOffset` and concatenate each filename. Use a debugger to inspect `ofn` upon return for all details.

Comment: It should also be hinted at that the `szFilePath` buffer in OP's code is way too small for multiple selection result and `CommDlgExtendedError()` should be called to check condition if buffer is too small.

Comment: If you read the documentation for the `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT`  flag, if multiple files are selected, the directory and list of filenames are separated by a NUL character, and `nFileOfset` points at the first filename, so `nFileOffset-1` would point at the NUL character after the directory. If a single file is selected, that NUL character is not present.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, small correction: if `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` is specified, there will always be a terminating double null, also if a single file is selected. If the flag is not specified, there will always be a single filename and no double null. There is never a null character after the directory; `nFileOffset` just points to the beginning of the filename in the full path and filename.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie "*There is never a NULL character after the directory*" - yes, there is. Clearly you did not read the documentation carefully enough: "***For Explorer-style dialog boxes, the directory and file name strings are NULL separated***". The OP is displaying an Explorer style dialog, and there is a NUL character after the directory when multiple files are selected. I tested it. See the code in my answer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: in your answer, "*to determine if the user has selected more than one file, go to the end of `lpstrFile` (i.e., to the first null), then check if there is another null following it, if not, then the user selected multiple files*" is wrong. If there is a delimiter character located at `nFileOffset-1`, multiple files are selected, otherwise one file is selected. If `OFN_EXPLORER` is specified, the delimiter is a null character, otherwise the delimiter is a space character. This is clearly outlined in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends to use the more modern [Common Item Dialog API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx) (available since Windows Vista) instead of `GetOpenFileName().`

With this API you don't have the hassle of splitting the file name buffer and handle the error condition if the provided buffer is too small (which would require you to call the API again with a bigger buffer). In your code the buffer (szFilePath) is **way too small** for multiple selection result so you will run into this error condition very soon if the user selects many files.

I'll first provide a short example only to show the sequence of API calls for using [`IFileOpenDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834(v=vs.85).aspx) with multiple selection.

## Short Example (scroll down for full code)

For brevity the following code has **no error handling at all**! You should check the HRESULT of each COM API call for failure, which I'll show in the full example after.

```
// Prepare the file open dialog.
CComPtr<IFileOpenDialog> dlg;
dlg.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FileOpenDialog );

dlg->SetOptions( fos | FOS_ALLOWMULTISELECT );

// Show the file open dialog.
dlg->Show( hwndOwner );
if( hr == S_OK ) // If user clicked OK button...
{
    CComPtr<IShellItemArray> items;
    dlg->GetResults( &items );

    DWORD numItems = 0;
    items->GetCount( &numItems );

    // Loop over all files selected by the user.
    for( DWORD i = 0; i < numItems; ++i )
    {
        CComPtr<IShellItem> item;
        items->GetItemAt( i, &item );

        CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> path;
        item->GetDisplayName( SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &path );

        std::wcout << std::wstring( path ) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

## Full Example with Error Handling

The following code shows how to use `IFileOpenDialog` and how to bridge the gap between C-style error reporting (HRESULT) and the C++ way of doing it (exceptions).

First we define a function `ShowFileOpenDialog()` that wraps `IFileOpenDialog` to make it easier to use. It returns a `std::vector` with the absolute pathes of the files selected by the user. If the user clicks "cancel" the vector will be empty. In case of any error it throws a `std::system_error` exception.

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>     // CComHeapPtr
#include <atlcomcli.h>  // CComPtr
#include <Shobjidl.h>   // IFileOpenDialog
#include <system_error>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void ThrowOnFail( HRESULT hr, char const* reason )
{
    if( FAILED(hr) )
        throw std::system_error( hr, std::system_category(), std::string("Could not ") + reason );
}

std::vector<std::wstring> ShowFileOpenDialog( 
    HWND hwndOwner, const std::vector<COMDLG_FILTERSPEC>& filter = {},
    FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS options = 0 )
{
    // Using CComPtr to automatically call IFileOpenDialog::Release() when scope ends.
    CComPtr<IFileOpenDialog> dlg;
    ThrowOnFail( dlg.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FileOpenDialog ), "instanciate IFileOpenDialog" );

    if( !filter.empty() )
        ThrowOnFail( dlg->SetFileTypes( filter.size(), filter.data() ), "set filetypes filter" );

    ThrowOnFail( dlg->SetOptions( options ), "set options" );

    HRESULT hr = dlg->Show( hwndOwner );
    if( hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_CANCELLED) )
        return {};
    ThrowOnFail( hr, "show IFileOpenDialog");

    CComPtr<IShellItemArray> items;
    ThrowOnFail( dlg->GetResults( &items ), "get results" );

    DWORD numItems = 0;
    ThrowOnFail( items->GetCount( &numItems ), "get result count" );

    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    result.reserve( numItems );

    for( DWORD i = 0; i < numItems; ++i )
    {
        CComPtr<IShellItem> item;
        ThrowOnFail( items->GetItemAt( i, &item ), "get result item" );

        // Using CComHeapPtr to automatically call ::CoTaskMemFree() when scope ends.
        CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> path;
        ThrowOnFail( item->GetDisplayName( SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &path ), "get result item display name" );

        // Construct std::wstring directly in the vector.
        result.emplace_back( path );
    }

    return result;
}
```

How to call this code and handle the exception:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(0);  // call once at application startup

    try 
    {
        HWND hwnd = nullptr;  // In a GUI app, specify handle of parent window instead.
        auto paths = ShowFileOpenDialog( hwnd, {{ L"Bitmap Files (*.bmp)", L"*.bmp" }},
                                         FOS_ALLOWMULTISELECT );
        if( paths.empty() )
        {
            // Cancel button clicked.
            std::cout << "No file(s) selected.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            // OK button clicked.
            for( const auto& path : paths )
                std::wcout << path << L"\n";
        }
    }
    catch( std::system_error& e )
    {
        std::cout 
            << "Could not show 'file open dialog'."
            << "\n\nCause: " << e.what()
            << "\nError code: " << e.code() << "\n";
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();  // match call of ::CoInitialize()
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although I appreciate pointing out the new interface, _this is C++_ and I would like to see the C version.